# What is exact mechanism of "push" using javascript and php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, firebase, push

I've found out firebase and according to the manuals and many articles about it, it would help creating push function in php project.

I can fully understand that with Curl, I can send data to firebase server. But I can't think decent idea to forward that data to target user in realtime. Javascript will enable that but isn't it quiet same with Ajax Polling?

With PHP and Javascript, and push cloud services like firebase, how can I make Realtime Push Notification? Rough sketch of mechanism would help!

Comment: read getting started in [firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup). simple google search will result in many online tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should have the '**device token**' for the device on which you want to send the push notification.Secondly you must have the '**server key**' which you can easily get from the firebase console.Now if you want to make realtime pushnotification just make an **ajax POST call** to the below function, which will take the **array** as an argument having the **devicetoken** and the **message** you want to pass in push notification.

```
public function sendNotification($postData = ""){

        //FCM api URL
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

        //api_key available in Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> CLOUD MESSAGING -> Server key
        $server_key = 'AAAA8mhm5CE:APA91bE420_Dl5GcRwpmNCvwB-m6QSLeEXhwTjNs5XR8RRSdBWcWkOuXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

        $data = $postData;

        $devicetoken = $data['devicetoken'];

        $message = $data['messege'];

        $fields = array (
            'registration_ids' => array (
                    $devicetoken
            ),

            'notification' => array (
                    "title" => "Title",
                    "text" => $message
            )
        );

        //header with content_type api key
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type:application/json',
            'Authorization:key='.$server_key
            );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take some time to read how to write a good answer. read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/338114) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thank you for the info. @SouravGhosh